# How do I set FTP passive mode in Spark?... to read a file from FTP Server

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am reading a file from `FTP server` into `spark` rdd like this

```scala
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("ftp://anonymous:pwd@<hostname>/data.gz")
rdd.count
...
```

This actually works when I run the spark application from my Local Machine (Mac), but when I try to run the same application from the ***docker container*** (running in Mac), I am getting the following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication.
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:313)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:479)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:552)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:601)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.quit(FTP.java:809)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.logout(FTPClient.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem.disconnect(FTPFileSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem.getFileStatus(FTPFileSystem.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.getPreferredLocationsForShuffle(MapOutputTracker.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.getPreferredLocations(ShuffledRDD.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$preferredLocations$2(RDD.scala:300)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:2098)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getPreferredLocs(DAGScheduler.scala:2072)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getPreferredLocs(SparkContext.scala:1794)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DefaultPartitionCoalescer.currPrefLocs(CoalescedRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DefaultPartitionCoalescer$PartitionLocations.$anonfun$getAllPrefLocs$1(CoalescedRDD.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DefaultPartitionCoalescer$PartitionLocations.getAllPrefLocs(CoalescedRDD.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DefaultPartitionCoalescer$PartitionLocations.<init>(CoalescedRDD.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.DefaultPartitionCoalescer.coalesce(CoalescedRDD.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD.getPartitions(CoalescedRDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1227)
    at com.mypackage.Myapp$.parseData(Myapp.scala:76)
```

In the container, even the `ftp` command line utility also have the same issue, but found out by setting the `passive` mode in `ftp` CLI, I am able to successfully transfer file from FTP server to the container,

```
ftp <host>
...
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> get data.gz
227 Entering Passive Mode ...
226 Transfer complete
20676672 bytes received in 25.53 secs (790.9552 kB/s)
```

So my question here is...How do I set the `passive mode` property?... when reading the file in Spark using `param.spark.sparkContext.textFile("ftp://anonymous:pwd@<hostname>/data.gz")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have experience with Spark, so I do not know how it glues with Hadoop. But in Hadoop, you can set up FTP passive mode by setting [`fs.ftp.data.connection.mode` configuration option](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.html):

```
fs.ftp.data.connection.mode=PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE
```

You need Hadoop 2.9 at least: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13953

Comment: hi Martin, Yep, the passive mode did the trick. Finally I am able to get this working in Spark. For someone who is working on spark; this what I have done
. Installed spark prebuilt for Hadoop 3.2 & later (as passive mode is supported only 
  from hadoop 2.9)
. The passive mode can either be configured in spark-submit or SparkConf. Pass the option in spar-submit like this `--conf spark.hadoop.fs.ftp.data.connection.mode="PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE"`